# finding the tag name which was asked for max number of times in the current year and also print the count

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().Timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-tags")).click();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("tagfilter"));
        element.sendKeys("qa");
        element.submit();
    }
```

I have written the above code but what would be the next?

Comment: Mike any clue on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I would assume that the most popular tag is the first one shown in the tags page.
```

Based on above assumption, you can try out the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\naveen\\mywork\\testing\\automation\\tools\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("nav-tags")).click();
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("tagfilter"));
    element.sendKeys("qa");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement popularTag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tags-browser']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"));
    System.out.println("most popular tag: " + popularTag.getText());
    WebElement populatTagCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tags-browser']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span/span[2]"));
    System.out.println("popular tag count " + populatTagCount.getText());
    WebElement tagCountAnual = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tags-browser']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]"));
    System.out.println("anaual count : " + tagCountAnual.getText());
    int anaualCount = Integer.parseInt(tagCountAnual.getText().split(" ")[0]);
    System.out.println("count " + anaualCount);
    driver.close();
```

Following is the output that i got:

```
most popular tag: qa
popular tag count 712
anaual count : 133 this year
count 133
```

you can cross check in the image:

[image]

Comment: This was to get the count for this week.

Comment: It is not weekly. I think it is the total number of times tag is used. the weekly count is 5851 for this week for javascript tag. you can refer at the bottom of javascript tag (in tags page). Can you show me where can we get annual counts?

Comment: If you type qa on  find tags and submit then you can get the count for this year

Comment: that won't solve your problem right? as it gives only tags with 'qa' as substring. do you want that? Or we need to consider all the tags?

Comment: when it gives the tag with qa. I was looking to get  the tag name which was  asked max  number of times in the current year and the count of it.

Comment: It's working but I was trying from css point of view.Anyways Thanks!

Comment: here it is, for css selector, WebElement tagCountAnual = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[id='tags-browser']>tbody>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(1)>div>div:nth-child(1)>a:nth-child(2)"));